# Zurb Foundation 6 and Orbit Error

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit

I am trying to use Orbit, and Foundation 6, without success. The pictures appear stacked one on top of the other, and do not change. I get a Javascript Error message in the Error Console.

If I remove the references to Orbit, the javascript error message does not appear.

Timestamp: 18/07/2016 12:51:46
Error: TypeError: We're sorry, object is not a valid parameter. You must use a string representing the method you wish to invoke.
Source File: http://lf/bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js
Line: 284

The bottom of the page, where the js files are called, is

```
</script>
<!--<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>-->
<script src='bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js'></script>
<script src='bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.orbit.js'></script>
<script>
    /*
    $(document).foundation();
    */   

    $(document).foundation({
        orbit: {
            animation: 'slide'

        }
    });
</script>
```

All the paths to the .js code are correct.

I am guessing that I have an incorrect version of something in there, but I don't know what.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Foundation 6 uses `jquery` and `jquery(version).min` or `jquery.js` should be the `first script` that you **should** refer.

Adding to that, I'm guess you did not go through the `Foundation 6 Orbit Slider` documentation's `JavaScript Reference` section.

[It says](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/orbit.html#js-module):

The file `foundation.orbit.js` must be included in your `JavaScript` to use this plugin, along with `foundation.core.js`. **This plugin also requires these utility libraries:**

`foundation.util.keyboard.js`, 
`foundation.util.motion.js`, 
`foundation.util.timerAndImageLoader.js` and
`foundation.util.touch.js`

So try referring these in your script space or use the `foundation.min.js` which will take care of all dependencies.

One more **important** thing, if you want to `animate` your slider, then you will **have to install and include [motion-ui](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/motion-ui.html) references** as mentioned in the `Orbit Slider` documentation's `Using Animation` section.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.

I found the code shown in my sample somewhere else, can't see where now! I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: I can't get the code in my reply to appear, despite trying both "4 spaces" and backticks - it just appears as one long row of text.  

I will try again later!

Comment: You have to leave a line (hit return/enter) and then leave four spaces in the second line for you code to appear.